# Can I including both MySQL and MySQLi database connection files?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have coded all my site with **mysqli**.
But most of the scripts I found from GitHub or other such sites are coded with **mysql**.

So, when implementing that in my projects should I **replace the mysql with mysqli** or use both of them in my **connection files** and all other **PHP files**??

Comment: Yes you can. But you should not.

Comment: _can i use them both?_ yes you can mix them both, so that you can make your life harder when the mysql API is obsolete and you'll have to rewrite those codes again

Answer (score 2):

You can use both of them. However this does not mean you should. **You should not use 2 connections**. For multiple reasons:

- Mysql is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future..
- Multiple database connections and more files which means performance issues.
- It's very confusing to work with 2 different connections **while it's not needed at all**.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from using both, but were I you I would choose one type of connection and go along with it. Mixing can be confusing not only for other people who read your code but also your future self.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to include both MySQL and MySQLi when connecting to a single database, but it is incredibly delicate and with large amounts of data being passed through it can get very messy and hard to control.

it is best to use MySQLi in general in my opinion because it is much more secure and up to date. Also, in the near future MySQL will be unsupported and your code will be uncompilable.

Comment: mysql_* API hasn't been supported for many years. While mysqli is ok, I strongly do not recommend using it either. Use PDO like everyone else